# Приложение Flask + uWSGI + nginx в CentOS8: UWSGI (service) не загружает приложение

Tags: flask, service, uwsgi, centos8

Подскажите, как решить такую проблему:

Сервер UWSGI, запускаемый сервисом (service), сообщает:

`*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***`
и соответственно браузер выдает "Internal server error"

При этом запуск UWSGI из командной строки (в том числе в виртуальном окружении -
`source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`) командой:
`uwsgi --ini runner.ini`
проходит нормально - мое приложение загружается
`WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1178740 pid: 1167 (default app)`
и в браузере все работает как надо.

Приложение размещено:

```
~/myapp/app
           __init__.py
           views.py
           ...
           /static
           /templates
           ...
       config.py
       runner.py
       wsgi.py
       runner.ini
       /myappenv/bin
       ...
```

**runner.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5
socket = runner.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

**runner.service** в /etc/systemd/system/

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve runner
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/pavlik/myapp
Environment="PATH=/home/pavlik/myapp/myappenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/pavlik/myapp/myappenv/bin/uwsgi --ini runner.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from runner import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**runner.py**

```
from app import app
import os
from flask_script import Manager, Shell

manager = Manager(app)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app)

manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

****init**.py**

```
rom flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager, Command, Shell
import os, config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') or 'config.DevelopementConfig')

from . import views
```

**config.py**

```
mport os

app_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class BaseConfig:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'A SECRET KEY'

class DevelopementConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False

class TestingConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False

class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
```

**views.py**

```
from app import app
import config
import re, datetime, random
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, make_response, session
from .forms import PhysPoForm, FirePoForm, FightPoForm, PsiPoForm
from .utils import res_to_score, save_to_db
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

@app.route('/')
def index():
... ...
```

Делал как написано в https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru - service UWSGI работает - приложение загружает, в браузере отображается

Подозреваю, что c моим приложением что-то не так с импортом и/или с путями к папкам приложения, но разобраться не могу :(

Comment: 1) a env FLASK_APP не нужен случайно? 2) зачем под root-ом запускать?

Comment: 1) думаю, что FLASK_APP нужен для сервера разработки (flask run); 2) если service запускается под обычным пользователем, то UWSGI ругается и на импорт различных пакетов, например flask_script, хотя они установлены

Comment: `__init__.py` vs `init.py`?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. __init__.py указывает на на папку приложения

Comment: я просто заметил, что в списке файлов одно, а содержимое приведено с другим названием

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Содержимое соответствует ```__init__.py```